# Problema ao utilizar um container do Docker com "port exposure" no Windows

Tags: windows, virtualbox, docker

Eu instalei o Docker no Windows esses dias mas estou tendo vários problemas ao rodar o meu container. Mesmo com ele em pé, não consigo acessar o projeto pelo navegador utilizando o IP da docker-machine, este é o comando que eu estou usando para rodar o container.

```
docker run -it -d -v /homer/user/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 myimage
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser? Ao acessar pelo navegador aparece a mensagem de "CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: E suponho que no seu container esteja rodando algo na porta 80, certo? O que você está rodando nele?

Comment: Adicione o dockerfile na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou colocar outra porta para ver se roda?

**Exemplo:**

```
docker run -it -d -v /homer/user/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 3000:80 myimage
```